# Connecting to SQL Server through Active Directory user in Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, virtual-machine

I am a beginer in Azure and I have been trying to accomplish below scenario task:

I have created two Virtual Machine say vm1 and vm2.

Virtual Machine (vm1) where I have installed:

- ADDS (Active Directory Domain Service): Window server 2012 R2
- Domain Name: `TestDomain` (example)
- ip: `10.0.0.79`
- user: `testuser@TestDomain.onmicrosoft.com`

In Virtual Machine (vm2), I have installed MS SQL server 2015. It is running and has a database on it. Then I have added the Domain name and configured DNS on vm2 with respect to vm1 (used same domain name: `TestDomain` and ip: `10.0.0.79`).

In vm2, from MS SQL, login with windows authenticaton mode, then Security >> Logins, right click new user then Search (user: `testuser@TestDomain.onmicrosoft.com`), then give the permission to the database for user from vm1.

Search that user from entire directory, then fetch, then gave database mapping and login entire permission to that user.

User appears: `TestDomain\testuser`.

Now when I try to login to database using user as: `TestDomain\testuser` or `testuser` or `testuser@TestDomain.onmicrosoft.com` and using same password that was used during creating in vm1, then I could not login.

I have looked several links, but could not find a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Active directory users and computers  : http://i.stack.imgur.com/nsJgl.jpg 
create user  : http://i.stack.imgur.com/TwK9o.jpg 
IP and DNS : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtVZT.png  
DNS : http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bmnf.png 
Fetching from active directory  : http://i.stack.imgur.com/isuDy.png

Comment: Are you connecting to sql server from a different computer? Did you already check this post https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-server-provision/#connect-to-sql-server-remotely

Comment: I'm able to connect to Sql Server from remote machine using user that has been created from sql  , but i want to login from users that has been fetch from the Active Directory, which is on another Virtual Machine

Comment: I have posted snapshot of above scenario

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format the inline code and paragraphs so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution as per the above question,
 but the solution is for web. I use
 "identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\username" password="password"/>",
which is added in config file.
Now, I have another problem , I want the solution for Desktop 
application like wpf or windows form.
Now, my question is can we do even for desktop application 
or we have alternative ways ?